# Where can I find free spatio-temporal dataset for download?

Tags: dataset, open-source, freebase

Where can I find free spatio-temporal dataset for download so that I can play with it in R ?

Comment: Could you be more specific into what you're looking for? does it matter?

Comment: I just want to have a look at the dataset such that I can perform data visualization , or even apply time series models to the dataset.

Comment: Would EEG data work for you? It's spatial (channel locations on the head) time series data.

Answer (score 9):

If you have R and the `spacetime` package then you are only `data(package="spacetime")` away from a list of space-time data sets bundled with the package:

```
Data sets in package ‘spacetime’:

DE_NUTS1 (air)          Air quality data, rural background PM10 in
                        Germany, daily averages 1998-2009
fires                   Northern Los Angeles County Fires
rural (air)             Air quality data, rural background PM10 in
                        Germany, daily averages 1998-2009
```

then for example:

```
> data(fires)
> str(fires)
'data.frame':   313 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Time: int  5863 5870 6017 6018 6034 6060 6176 6364 6366 6372 ...
 $ X   : num  63.9 64.3 64.1 64 64.4 ...
 $ Y   : num  19.4 20.1 19.7 19.8 20.3 ...
```

Answer (score 5):

First thing that came to mind would be one's personal workout data from running or biking apps.

Otherwise there is a dataset around NYC's taxi trip data. Quick Googling brought me this: http://www.andresmh.com/nyctaxitrips/. Variables include time and location for both pickups and dropoffs.

Another dataset comes from Chicago's bikesharing service. It can be found here: https://www.divvybikes.com/datachallenge.

Answer (score 3):

You can get some documented, publicly available EEG data from the HeadIT database at UCSD.
http://headit-beta.ucsd.edu/studies

The data itself appears to be in Biosemi Data Format (.bdf) files, described here: http://www.biosemi.com/faq/file_format.htm

Biosemi provides links to several open-source methods to access and import .bdf files on their website, including several functions for importing into Matlab, as well as into Python (BioSig) and C/C++ libraries:
http://www.biosemi.com/download.htm

Just as a forewarning, EEG data can be a bit of a bear to work with, due to it's inherently low signal/noise ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to combine OpenStreetMap project map data, for example, using corresponding nice R package (http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-openstreetmap-package-opens-up), with census data (population census data, such as the US data: http://www.census.gov/data/data-tools.html, as well as census data in other categories: http://national.census.okfn.org) to analyze temporal patterns of geosocial trends. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can get yellow and green taxi trip records from NYC taxi dataset. The website collects data from 2009 until now. You can download the data from the following link: http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml